# trying to achieve a design with labels aligned vertically

Tags: html, css

[image]

The line in the center is not there, just to create a bifurcation.
Adding long text should not move the column label to the left, the position should be fixed

```css
.wid {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<table class="wid">
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Bill asfsafsafasfasfasfasdfasGates</td>

    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <th>Naasdfasdfme:</th>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Adding table-layout:fixed; does this

[image]

Comment: If I inlcude more text it distorts and moves the labels to the left

Comment: take a lokk at table-layout  here on a search engine or . try `table {table-layout:fixed;}` then see what happens and look for it to know why it does ;) .if it is not about the red line not moving, then clarify a bit more what you mean about the label (there's only th and td  in the code

Comment: Edited the description and it goes to the next column

Comment: okay, and what is it supposed to do in that case ? if such a word exists  :)

Comment: I wish if we can reduce the size of the label columns and give a little more space for the descriptions

Comment: if i understand, labels are th , and your second label should start at 50 of your table width, while the label columns should wrap as much as possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Use word-wrap property to break the text to next line.

```css
.wid {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}

td, th{
   word-wrap: break-word; /*Breaks the word to the next line when cell space runs out*/

 }

th{
width:10%; /*Change the percent value to adjust the table label width*/
 
}
```

```html
<table class="wid">
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Bill asfsafsafasfasfasfasdfasGates</td>

    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <th>Naasdfasdfme:</th>
    <td>Bill Gateffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: Set width:10% for th in response to the comment.

Comment: That works but if we can give more space for the description column and little less space for the label column

Comment: Changed it now. <th> occupies 10% of the overall width and <td> will take the rest.